# Can we add, subtract, multiply, or divide each side of an equation by a unit if there are already units on both sides?

Tags: dimensional-analysis, unit-of-measure

Can we add, subtract, multiply, or divide each side of an equation by a unit if there are already units on both sides?

Do they just work like numbers?

Example 1

$$ 12 packs \cdot 10 dollars/pack = 120 dollars. $$

Can it be, say (don't know what the new unit means but is it valid mathemetically?):

$$13meters\cdot (12 packs \cdot 10 dollars/pack) = 13meters\cdot120 dollars.$$

or (be divided by a unit and become pure numbers)

$$ 12 packs \cdot 10 dollars/pack = 120 dollars. $$

$$ 120 dollars = 120 dollars. $$

$$ 1/dollars\cdot120 dollars = 1/dollars\cdot120 dollars. $$

$$ 120 = 120  $$

Comment: Yes you can, they are the exact same as variables in an equation. It is a useful thing to check the units on a final answer - are they what you expect? You can only add/subtract expressions with the same units too. It also occurs in dimensional analysis, you can work out what an equation should be just by looking at the variables sometimes.

Comment: See also [the factor label method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis#The_factor-label_method_for_converting_units).